# Can't put multiple image in the same tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to put 2 image in the same tinter window

```
###-------Making the main Information-----=-#####
canvas = Canvas(main_WINDOW, width = 50, height = 50)
canvas.place(x=370, y=124)
img = PhotoImage(file="Target.png")
canvas.create_image (0,0, anchor=NW, image=img)

mycanvas = Canvas(main_WINDOW, width = 50, height = 50)
mycanvas.place(x=1200, y=124)
img = PhotoImage(file="Target copy.png")
mycanvas.create_image (0,0, anchor=NW, image=img)
```

I have try this code and the only one appear is the Target copy.png while the Target.png only the canvas appear.

Comment: You have to keep a reference to each `PhotoImage` object or it will be garbage-collected.  When you stored your second image as `img`, the first one disappeared.  Use separate variable names, or perhaps append all images to a list if there's going to be an arbitrary number of them.

Answer (score 0):

You must keep a reference to tkinter images. Since you use `img` for both images, you end up with a single reference to the last image that you created. Either store the image references in separate variables, or in a list.

Using individual variables:

```
...
img1 = PhotoImage(file="Target.png")
...
img2 = PhotoImage(file="Target copy.png")
```

Using a list:

```
images = []
...
img = PhotoImage(file="Target.png")
images.append(img)
...
img = PhotoImage(file="Target copy.png")
images.append(img)
...
```